# Clarification about the post: Russian hackers use ‘zero-day’ to hack NATO, Ukraine in cyber-spy campaign

Tags: attacks, zero-day, defense

I have encountered the following article on Washington post: 
[Russian hackers use ‘zero-day’ to hack NATO, Ukraine in cyber-spy campaign](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/russian-hackers-use-zero-day-to-hack-nato-ukraine-in-cyber-spy-campaign/2014/10/13/f2452976-52f9-11e4-892e-602188e70e9c_story.html).

As always in such kind of articles the publication sounds too scary. There is almost no information to understand what are they talking about.

Can anyone understand what kind of vulnerability are they talking about and explain in more technical terms what happened?

Comment: @paj28 thank you for your comment. I thought that if this is an important vulnerability, someone already have outlined some technical details. Because this article tells me nothing.

Comment: Until the patch is released, it is in Microsoft's (and most peoples) best interests that info does not come out.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I know, but most interests not always agrees to what happens in the real word. There always will be people who knows something and this is exactly why I have asked the question.

Comment: I know. I was explaining why you hadn't yet seen any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A description from [isightpartners](http://www.isightpartners.com/2014/10/cve-2014-4114/) (English), and description from [Eset's blog](http://habrahabr.ru/company/eset/blog/240345/) (Russian).

Embedded OLE object in Power Point document somehow can download and install .inf files and executable files.